# Windows IoT core image creation with custom UWP application is not working

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

I have followed the below msdn step by step guide to create a custom windows IoT core image, but I am unable to load my Hello_World UwP app in the image. It looks like the Hello world app depends on two packages Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx and Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00.appx, these dependencies are not getting installed as part of the app install command.

I have also tried to run the powershell script to install the Uwp package with dependencies added, but in that case it shows that the default account has no privilege to execute these commands as part of the install app script.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/iot/deploy-your-app-with-a-standard-board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because the [IoT Core ADK Add-Ons](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/) was containing a different version of the ApInstall.cmd files. That was using the deployappx.exe for deploying the Uwp packages but it failed to deploy the dependent packages.

I have used the appinstall command files from the [IOT Samples](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/AppInstaller) project in the below url, and it worked.It is using the mindeployappx.exe for deploying the UWP package with dependencies.